# Error when booting Kali-Linux

Tags: debian, kali-linux

When I'm trying to boot Kali Linux from an USB-Device I get this error:

```
/bin/sh: cannot open /dev/tty1: No such file
/bin/sh: cannot open /dev/tty1: No such file
/bin/sh: cannot open /dev/tty1: No such file
/bin/sh: cannot open /dev/tty1: No such file
/bin/sh: cannot open /dev/tty1: No such file
/bin/sh: cannot open /dev/tty1: No such file
/bin/sh: cannot open /dev/tty1: No such file
/bin/sh: cannot open /dev/tty1: No such file
/bin/sh: cannot open /dev/tty1: No such file
/bin/sh: cannot open /dev/tty1: No such file
INIT: Id "1" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes
INIT: no more processes left in this runlevel
```

I installed it onto my USB-Device using Universial USB Installer and Win32DiskImager. None of them worked.

Comment: what if you try writing image with dd?